# Convert PIL Image to byte array?

Tags: python, image, arrays, python-imaging-library

I have an image in PIL Image format. I need to convert it to byte array.

```
img = Image.open(fh, mode='r')  
roiImg = img.crop(box)
```

Now I need the `roiImg` as a byte array.

Comment: Please supply more detail. In what format is the byte array supposed to be? The raw pixels values are available via `Image.getdata()`, which returns the internal representation PIL uses for an image in a particular format on a particular platform.

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds like you need to use the`Image`'s [`getdata()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) method.

Comment: My objective is to save the image in mysql database as a BLOB type.

Comment: `imgByteArr = open("foo.png" 'rb').read()`  Need `roiImg` in the same format as `imgByteArr`

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.

Finally got it resolved!!

```
import io
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(fh, mode='r')
roi_img = img.crop(box)

img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
roi_img.save(img_byte_arr, format='PNG')
img_byte_arr = img_byte_arr.getvalue()
```

With this i don't have to save the cropped image in my hard disc and I'm able to retrieve the byte array from a PIL cropped image.

Comment: can you please add import io?

Comment: For `format="jpg"` saving to bytes does not work while `"jpeg"` works for both files and bytes and `"jpg"` works for files only.

Comment: How do I do the reverse of this? Any ideas?

Comment: @Mooncrater I believe it's like this: `stream = io.BytesIO(img_byte_array)` and then `img = Image.open(stream)`

Comment: Why `roi_img.tobytes()` does not work?

Comment: @Simone: Because of the requirement missing from the question but mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101935/convert-pil-image-to-byte-array#comment54021344_33101935), that the result should be PNG-compressed.

Answer (score 63):

This is my solution:

```py
from PIL import Image
import io

def image_to_byte_array(image: Image) -> bytes:
  # BytesIO is a file-like buffer stored in memory
  imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
  # image.save expects a file-like as a argument
  image.save(imgByteArr, format=image.format)
  # Turn the BytesIO object back into a bytes object
  imgByteArr = imgByteArr.getvalue()
  return imgByteArr
```

Comment: What is the UTF returned?

Answer (score 9):

I think you can simply call the PIL image's `.tobytes()` method, and from there, to convert it to an array, use the `bytes` built-in.

```
#assuming image is a flattened, 3-channel numpy array of e.g. 600 x 600 pixels
bytesarray = bytes(Image.fromarray(array.reshape((600,600,3))).tobytes())
```

Comment: From documentation https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes it is not recomended, as it save raw image data for each pixel. If you use PNG, JPG, e.t.c. then need to use BytesIO() in Image.save()

Comment: Ah, I see. For my purposes, I didn't need the bytes data, since I immediately do numerical processing on the RBG values. Also, the question doesn't mention anything about saving the images, only converting them. Consider removing your down vote for that reason.

Answer (score -4):

Python file read and extract binary array

```py
import base64
with open(img_file_name, "rb") as f:
    image_binary = f.read()
    base64_encode = base64.b64encode(image_binary)
    byte_decode = base64_encode.decode('utf8')
```