# AttributeError: read when trying to use BytesIO with PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I'm trying to convert my image from rgba to rgb using PIL then detect the most used colors using [Color-Thief-Py](https://github.com/fengsp/color-thief-py). However when I try to pass the rgb converted image into to the colorthief function, I get the following error: `AttributeError: read`.

Here's the code:

```
logo = request.FILES.get('logo')
rgba_img = Image.open(logo)
rgb_img = rgba_img.convert('RGB')
color = io.BytesIO(rgb_img.read()) #AttributeError: read
color_thief = ColorThief(color)
```

What am I doing wrong & How can I resolve it?

Comment: That's badly phrased and i'm not sure what you really want. But ```rgb_img``` is of type *Image*. There is no read()-method. You can use ```rgb_img.save()``` to write an image (for example into BytesIO). But it's not guaranteed that your next pipeline-step is expecting this (probably won't take a bytestream which is actually jpeg2000). Maybe it requires uncompressed pixel-data and you will need to prepare it using ```rgb_img.getdata()```. But we don't know...

Comment: Just pass the filepath to [ColorThief](https://github.com/fengsp/color-thief-py/blob/18a099ba3d9f649406ab1cfa75990df1cf658f03/colorthief.py#L35) ??

Comment: @wwii I'd like to convert my image to rgb first, if the background of my image is transparent it won't take it into account...

Comment: Did you read the PIL docs?? Are you getting an error with ```rgb_image.read()```?

Comment: maybe this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33117447/2823755

Comment: You're **not** getting the error when you try to pass the rgb converted img into the colorthief function. `PIL.Image.Image` instances don't have a `read()` method, so that's why you're getting the `AttributeError`. See the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#the-image-class) of the `Image` class.

Comment: Instead of using `rgb_img.read()`, try using `rgb_img.tobitmap()`, `rgb_img.tobytes()`, or `rgb_img.tostring()` depending on what `ColorThief()` accepts/expects as an argument. As always, consult the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobitmap) to see what's available.