# PostgreSQL can't escape JpegImageFile to binary, psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, image, psycopg2

**ubuntu 18.04 - Python 3.6.7 - psycopg2 2.7.6.- Postgresql 10.8**

Saving an image in a bytea Posgtres field, cause psycopg2 to rise the following error (test code in Spyder3):

**Error while connecting to PostgreSQL can't escape JpegImageFile to binary**

IF I run the same code in Eclipse-pydev, the error reported is similar but gives type information:
**TypeError: can't escape JpegImageFile to binary**

-Can you understand if the problem is related to Postgresql or to psycopg2?
-How can make we succed in saving the image file in Postgresql ?
-May it be a library error ?

Saving an **image** in Postregsql require to use a **bytea field type**.
The image needs to be **encoded**  in hex format or bytea escape format.
If we read an url image, **convert** it by psycopg2 in **Bynary**, 
BUT
when finally executing INSERT query, the function return the said error.
the following code can reproduce the error:

```py
import psycopg2
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests

url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a3/Eq_it-na_pizza-margherita_sep2005_sml.jpg/440px-Eq_it-na_pizza-margherita_sep2005_sml.jpg'
#image = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
response = requests.get(url)
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
#test image correctly read
width, height = image.size
print (width,height)   
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "user",
                password = "odoo12", host = "127.0.0.1",
                port = "5432",database = "dbname")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = """INSERT INTO foods (fo_image, fo_url) 
                VALUES (%s,%s) ;"""
    byteImage = psycopg2.Binary(image)        
    data = (byteImage, url )
    cursor.execute(query,data)
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
        print ("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
finally:
        #closing database connection.
            if(connection):
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()
```

The image is checked against size and shows right info.
Changing different images shows  same result.
What is going wrong ? How to fix it ?_

Comment: Surely you want to save the actual bytes, not the python Image object you have constructed from them?

Comment: I put your idea in 2 ways below, 
I get NO error, BUT... NO record written in memory. 

1) save Image to bytearray  and then pass it to psycopg2 as in
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101935/convert-pil-image-to-byte-array -
byteImage = psycopg2.Binary(image_to_byte_arra(image))

2) get response.content and pass it directly to psycopg2.Binary():
byteImage = psycopg2.Binary(response.content)

table is 
CREATE TABLE public.foods(
 fo_food_id_pk serial NOT NULL,
 fo_image bytea,
 fo_url varchar,
 CONSTRAINT foods_pk PRIMARY KEY (fo_food_id_pk)

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the `psycopg2.Binary` in python 3.

I suspect you aren't calling `connection.commit()` to commit the transaction.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your help.
I tested you ideas, and confirm BOTH options (response.contet & img2bytea)  works WITHOUT the need of psycopg2.Binary: just few difference in data written: image2bytearray: 51001 ; response.content: 39043; One more question: When I’ll read back the   byteimage = cursor.fetchone[0], which is the best way to generate the Image object ? Storing the object with response.content or img2ba, makes any differece in generating the Image?