# AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'getvalue' (PIL)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I currently am working on a program that pastes two images together with PIL, but PIL is weird, so I had to do a bunch of extra stuff so that I could use links. Anyways, now I can't use what PIL outputted because:
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'getvalue'

here's the important chunk of my code:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(avurl) as second_image:
        image_bytes = await second_image.read()

with Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes)).convert("RGB") as first_image:
    output_buffer = BytesIO()
    first_image.save(output_buffer, "png")
    output_buffer.seek(0)

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get("https://i.imgur.com/dNS0WJO.png") as second_image:
        image_bytes = await second_image.read()

with Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes)) as second_image:
    output_buffer = BytesIO()
    second_image.save(output_buffer, "png")
    output_buffer.seek(0)

first_image.paste(second_image, (0, 0))
buf = io.BytesIO()
first_image.save(buf, "png")
first_image = first_image.getvalue()
```

could anyone tell me what line of code i'm missing to fix this? or maybe what i did incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Image objects indeed do not have a `getvalue` method, it's `BytesIO` instances that do.
Here you should be calling `buf.getvalue` instead of `first_image.getvalue`.

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
first_image.save(buf, "png")
first_image = first_image.getvalue()
```

Your code looks a bit like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33117447/7051394 ; but if you look at the last three lines of that snipper, `imgByteArr` is still a `BytesIO`, so `imgByteArr.getvalue()` is valid.

Comment: if i do
 
   first_image.save(buf, "png")
    buf = buf.getvalue()
    file = discord.File(fp=buf, filename="pfp.png")

i get:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: This looks like a different problem, you'd be better off asking another question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler and possibly faster reformulation of your code:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    image1data = await session.get(avurl).read()
    image2data = await session.get("https://i.imgur.com/dNS0WJO.png").read()

image1 = Image.open(BytesIO(image1data)).convert("RGB")
image2 = Image.open(BytesIO(image2data))

image1.paste(image2, (0, 0))
buf = BytesIO()
image1.save(buf, "png")
composite_image_data = buf.getvalue()
```

You'll end up with `composite_image_data` containing PNG data for the composited image.