# PIL Image as Bytes with BytesIO to prevent hard disk saving

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, bytesio

**Problematic**

I have a PIL Image and i want to convert it to a bytes array. I can't save the image on my hard disk so i can't use the default `open(file_path, 'rb')` function.

**What i tried**

To overturn this problem i'm trying to use the `io` library doing this :

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
image.save(buf, format='JPEG')
b_image = buf.getvalue()
```

Considering image as a functional PIL Image.

the "b_image" will be used as argument for the Microsoft Azure cognitives services function `read_in_stream()`

If we look in the documentation, we can see that this function image argument have to be :

> image
> xref:Generator

> Required

> An image stream.

Documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision/azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.operations.computervisionclientoperationsmixin?view=azure-python#read-in-stream-image--language--en---custom-headers-none--raw-false--callback-none----operation-config-)

**The issue**

When i execute it i got the error :

> File "C:...\envs\trainer\lib\site-packages\msrest\service_client.py", line 137, in stream_upload
> chunk = data.read(self.config.connection.data_block_size)

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

There is no error in the client authentification or at another point because when i give as parameter an image imported with this line :

`image = open("./1.jpg", 'rb')`

Everything is working correctly..

**Sources**

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101935/convert-pil-image-to-byte-array/33117447) post that explains exactly what i want to do but in my case it's not working. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we use the method `read_in_stream`, we need to provide a stream. But the code `BytesIO.getvalue` will return the content of the stream as string or bytes. So please update code as below

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
image.save(buf, format='JPEG')
computervision_client.read_in_stream(buf)
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/f40a0ffe9bfa6843370ce3c1979021cc7b0bfb99/sdk/cognitiveservices/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision/azure/cognitiveservices/vision/computervision/operations/_computer_vision_client_operations.py#L1505)

---

**Update**

Regarding the issue, I suggest you use rest API to implement your need.

```
import io
import requests
from PIL import Image
import time
url = "{your endpoint}/vision/v3.1/read/analyze"
key = ''
headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
}

// process image
...
with io.BytesIO() as buf:
    im.save(buf, 'jpeg')
    response = requests.request(
        "POST", url, headers=headers, data=buf.getvalue())
    
    # get result

    while True:
        res = requests.request(
            "GET", response.headers['Operation-Location'], headers=headers)
        status = res.json()['status']
        if status == 'succeeded':
            print(res.json()['analyzeResult'])
            break
        time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that too but when i do that i got the following error: >line 1567, in read_in_stream
    raise models.ComputerVisionErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models._models_py3.ComputerVisionErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'

Comment: But if do that : ```stream = io.BytesIO()      image.save(stream, format='JPEG')     f = open("file.txt", "wb")     f.write(stream.getvalue())      f = open("file.txt", "rb")``` and i give f as parameter it works perfectly but i don't want to use file

Comment: Thank you. it's working with this syntaxe