# Convert pillow Image object to bytes object in order to store it in a blob column

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am reading a bytes file, convert that and then Open it. I need to convert this back to bytes in order to store it in the database in a blob column.

How is this possible to convert actual image to bytes?

```
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(dfa.flal_file)).convert('RGB')
```

Comment: In pillow there is `Image.tobytes()`, see [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=image#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101935/convert-pil-image-to-byte-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert PIL Image to byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101935/convert-pil-image-to-byte-array)

Comment: Surely, `dfa.flal_file` is a JPEG or PNG anyway, so just store that. And it has the height and width in it. If you just store bytes, you won't know the image dimensions or colourspace or EXIF data.

Comment: @guidot yes it did