# How to upload a numpy.ndarray image into Azure Storage Blob

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, numpy-ndarray

I would like to upload an image numpy.ndarray data into Azure Storage Blob. I am using the BlobServiceClient. But I cannot find a way for upload_blob to accept a numpy.ndarray. How can I upload it?

```
     blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(
         container=CONTAINER, blob=filename)

     blob_client.upload_blob(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should encode your `np.ndarray` into bytes first.

```
import numpy as np
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from PIL import Image
account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>'
container_name = '<your container name>'
blob_name = 'image.jpg'  # my test image name
img: np.ndarray = []  # Load your image.
im = Image.fromarray(img)
img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
im.save(img_byte_arr, format='jpeg')
img_byte_arr = img_byte_arr.getvalue()
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name, account_key)
blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(container_name, blob_name, img_byte_arr)
```

Resources:

[1. Using PIL to convert Numpy array into bytes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101935/convert-pil-image-to-byte-array)